# Mysql paging - by id or time?

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a social application which needs paging for the posts.

Here is the database:

```
id       | post          | time     | 
---------|---------------|----------|
1        | "oldest"      |  9:00    |
2        | "old"         | 10:00    |
3        | "new"         | 11:00    |
4        | "newest"      | 12:00    |
```

**In my app:**

Newest posts are on top and I only load 2 posts at the time.

Let's say the first 2 data is loaded into the app

> - 4 (12:00) newest
> - 3 (11:00) new

User scrolls down, the app detects that the last post was reached, so it requests the PHP file to download 2 more the following order:

> - 2 (10:00) old
> - 1 (9:00) older

It works fine. The following is my code:

```
$qry = $db->prepare('SELECT id, post
  FROM posts
  WHERE id < :lastLoadedId
  ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0, 2');
```

---

**The problem / question:**

My server deletes really old posts automatic (in order to save space)

Let's assume that after a while the mysql table reaches it's limitations (last available id which is 2,147,483,647)

Then I need to give ids again from 1:

here comes the problem.

```
id            | post          | time     | 
--------------|---------------|----------|
1             | "new"         | 11:00    |
2             | "newest"      | 12:00    |
2,147,483,646 | "oldest"      | 9:00     |
2,147,483,647 | "old"         | 10:00    |
```

The first 2 data is loaded again into my app.

> - 2 (12:00) newest
> - 1 (11:00) new

When it tries to load more, it searches for IDs that are smaller than number 2, but since 2,147,483,647 is bigger therefore it would not return back the "oldest" and "old" posts.

---

Should I worry about this?

How does big companies handle that much data? After a while they start a new table?

Comment: use big integer if you worried about integer overflow

Comment: _“Then I need to give ids again from 1”_ - no you don’t; IDs _never_ get re-used this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL website, the unsigned bigint can go up to 18446744073709551615. If you insert 1 million records per second 24x7, it will take 584542 years to reach the limit. So I don't think you should worry too much.

Here is an example :

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Note that the 20 stands for the number of digits to be displayed and has nothing to do with storage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding another column ?

```
ALTER TABLE `files` ADD `real_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AFTER `id`;
```

So before adding an article, search for the last (biggest) real_id and then increment it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your design.

1. Your id is not a real id. The id should be primary key and auto increment. There shouldn't be a case of reusing id. It's confusing.
2. Your id data type INT is not enough to support real life data. As suggested by other developers, change it to bigint.
3. MySQL internally stores date time or timestamp as integer. The size impact is small. But you should use Id only (order by id desc, instead of time) and make sure it's primary key. This will make your query very fast because it's directly working on the clustered index